# App screen is blank after app did become active when adding custom UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, cordova

I wrote a small plugin for a Cordova based application which goal is to prevent screenshots.

I followed the approach to add a secure text field. This works well if the app is started from killed state (not from background). If the app resumes from background (app did become active), the app only displays a blank (white) screen.

I assume the text field view is on top of the WebView, so that only this view is visible?

For testing purposes I tried to remove the text field (`removeTextField()`) when app resigns active, but I could not remove the field at all.

Surely I miss something, but how do I prevent the screen from getting blanked when app resumes active?

```
class WebExPlugin : CDVPlugin {
    
    var isEnabled = false
    
    override func pluginInitialize() {
        enable(completion: nil)
    }

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.handleWillResignActiveNotification),
                                               name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)

    @objc public func enable(completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        self.isEnabled = true
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.webView.addSecureTextField()
            completion?()
        }
    }

    @objc public func disable(completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        self.isEnabled = false
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.webView.removeTextField()
            completion?()
        }
    }
    
    // just for testing purposes: disable when app goes to background
    @objc public func handleWillResignActiveNotification() {
        if self.isEnabled {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // chnaged to superview based on answer.
                self.webView?.superview!.removeTextField()
            }
        }
    }
}

public extension UIView {
    func addSecureTextField() {
        let field = UITextField()
        field.isSecureTextEntry = true
        field.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        field.tag = 101;
        self.addSubview(field)
        field.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        field.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(field.layer)
        field.layer.sublayers?.last?.addSublayer(self.layer)
    }

    // does not work! 
    func removeTextField() {
        // code updated thanks to suggestion from @T.Pasichnyk
        self.viewWithTag(101)?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Edit:
View hierarchy from view debugger:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so it seems I solved the main issue.

Calling superview does the trick. However, removing the text field still fails.

```
@objc public func enable(completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.webView?.superview!.addSecureTextField()
        completion?()
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `viewWithTag(101)?.removeFromSuperview()`? You don't need to iterate through all the subviews. EDIT: Are you sure it is even in the view hierarchy? Could you post a view debugger screenshot? Also, I don't see where `removeTextField()`. Could you please add that code?

Comment: Thanks @T.Pasichnyk for your help! I tried to find it, but could not. Frankly I don't know if the view is there or not. I could not find a view with the defined tag. Please see the edit to my original post. I added a screenshot and the test code to remove the text field.

Comment: I found the view using `self.viewController.view.viewWithTag(101)`, you can call `self.viewController?.view.viewWithTag(101)?.removeFromSuperview()`, it should work. Cordova swizzles UIKit classes and methods, but I don't have time (and hate Cordova) to explain properly.

Also, why do you need extension for UIView? Just create few methods in the plugin extension to handle that, or at least make extension private?

Comment: Very strange, that does not work for me. But will accept it for now, the disable feature is not so important right now. Regarding extension for UIView: That was mainly for testing purposes, will move it to the plugin extension. Thanks for taking your time, despite the Cordova related question.

Comment: While adding a subview you are also adding a layer for some reason. Need to remove that as well, probably. Not sure, why you do that. Adding a subview should be enough.

Comment: Alright, thanks again. Adding the layer is necessary for it to work (otherwise the screenshot would show the content of the "webpage"). Will look at it tomorrow, on how to remove the layer.

Comment: Out of intrest, why don't you use an existing plugin for that purpose, like https://github.com/flotrugliocoffice/cordova-plugin-prevent-screenshot-coffice,
https://github.com/devgeeks/PrivacyScreenPlugin or https://github.com/lifeofcoding/cordova-blur-app-privacy-screen ?

Comment: All those available plugins do not "prevent" taking a screenshot, they only hide the screenshot in the app switcher. However I want to hide the content if a screenshot is taken.